# Definition of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation

What is the ring $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$? What does this notation mean?

Comment: The smallest subring of $\Bbb{C}$ (or other suitable umbrella ring) that contains both $\Bbb{Z}$ and $\sqrt n$. A simpler description specific to square roots of integers can be given (assuming $n$ is an integer):
$$\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt n]=\{a+b\sqrt n\mid a,b\in\Bbb{Z}\},$$ but that fails, when $\sqrt{n}$ is replaced with a number of another type such as a cube root

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen What is an umbrella ring? Please use standard terminology (just kidding)

Answer (score 2):

It is the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers together with some element $x$ such that $x^2=n$. It can be seen as a smallest subring of, say, $\mathbb{C}$, that contains both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\sqrt{n}$ (in fact, any subring of $\mathbb{C}$ contains $\mathbb{Z}$).

Alternativelly, we can define $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$ as the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ factored by the ideal $(X^2-n)$, that is, we force $X$ to be the square root of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb Z[\sqrt{n}]$ is define as $\{ a+b\sqrt{n}: a,b \in \Bbb Z\} .$ It's not difficult to see that this Is a ring. In particular this is the smallest subring of $\Bbb C$ containing $\Bbb Z$ and $\sqrt{n}$ at the same time.